# Are questions on stand-up shows on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Could stand-up shows be discussed on Movies.SE?

I'm aware that such a category could easily be abused because it's hard to distinguish between the "show" and the comedians themselves but nevertheless shouldn't the comedians also be discussed here? They are mostly "media" people; I mean it's hard to separate the comedians from their recorded materials and of course their production teams. There is a thin line between the comedians' world view and their media products but should they be separated?

We do discuss the artistic approach, the world view, the philosophy of the directors, actors, producers etc all the time. Why should the comedians be treated differently?

Comment: I suspect this is going to be entirely question-dependent.

Comment: In my opinion we should allow questions about everything that is a part of a clearly identified TV show and only that. I'd see a general discussion about a comedian rather off-topic, the comparison with directors, actors and producers is not the best, because all their work is on topic, which is not the case for comedians. It's normal that "a broader picture" can appear in answers, because as you wrote _there is a thin line between the comedians' world view and their media products_, but for questions I would stick to the stuff that's strictly related to TV.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong Could you elaborate on this a little more? For example would a question such as 'What does George Carlin mean when he says in the show xxx that "blah blah blah" ' be a valid question?. Because this is what I'm looking for in asking about stand-up shows. I'm not interested in questions like 'Where and when was the show xxx filmed' or 'Why did Louis CK change his producer between the shows xxx and yyy'.

Comment: IMO it would be a valid question since you refer a TV show.

Comment: @ChanandlerBong I'm not sure he actually refers to a TV show there, rather than a live stand-up comedy show. A little clarification from his side might be required here.

Comment: @Montag451 Can you give some clarification and some examples

Comment: Look at our sports,  or wrestling policy. Q's about the technical or rules aspects of the sports are off topic (how does a suplex work, Was that pick legal?) But questions on the history of the tv show, or plot related (why did stone cold hate Kurt angle?) Is on topic.